# Unwanted segue after if-else Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am checking if my label's and image (image is linked with label, so just checking label) to see if the user can proceed. If he has filled all the details (using pickerView and datePicker) user can proceed. Else user get's an alert  to fill the details and should stay on the same page.

Below is the code I am using. Everything works, but the app performs unwanted segue after getting the alert.

Unwanted problem is of two types:

1. If I directly click go to NEXT page (without touching the pickerViews), it will show me the alert but when I click OK, it will perform a segue to the previous page.
2. On the other hand, if I complete all the details as needed, Click NEXT (it takes me to the next view controller as required) and than if I click BACK from that viewcontroller to the initial picker view's everything works as required. But than if I click next without performing picker view action, this time it shows me the alert and takes me to the NEXT view controller.

So basically the problem is,

- if I don't fill details, I get alert and get a segue to previous view controller
- if I fill details, click next, than click back to the same picker selection view controller, and than click next without touching I get a segue to next view controller.

I Just want it to stay at the current view controller (picker view selection page) after the alert. What am I doing wrong?

CODE IS AS FOLLOWS:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (xLabel.text! != "" && yLabel.text! != "") {

        var user = PFUser.currentUser()
        var myGender: AnyObject! = user["gender"]
        var myName: AnyObject! = user["name"]
        var DestView : UserDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UserDetailViewController
        DestView.uDetailName = "\(myName)"
        DestView.uDetailGender = "\(myGender)"
        DestView.uDetailBar = "\(xLabel.text!)"
        DestView.uDetailDate = dateLabel.text!
        DestView.uDetailBarPic = PickerViewImage.image!
        DestView.uDetailQuantity = "\(yLabel.text!)"
    } else {

        self.displayAlert("Could not proceed", error: "Please select 'Location' and 'Number of people' to proceed")
    }
}

func displayAlert(title:String, error:String) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { action in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`prepareForSegue` is too late to make decisions about whether the segue should be executed - at this point the segue is already committed.

You should implement the function `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`. You return a Boolean from this function that indicates whether you want the segue to proceed.

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String!, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
    if (xLabel.text! != "" && yLabel.text! != "") {
       return true
    } else {    
         self.displayAlert("Could not proceed", error: "Please select 'Location' and 'Number of people' to proceed")
       return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What I understood from this is, now I am checking first if the condition is met, if it's met, it will proceed to segue, else an alert will be displayed. So now I have two functions - one shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier and prepareForSegue. But I am still getting the same problem. Is it because I am messing up the destination view controller? I am sorry, I am new in coding, so may be talking foolish here. Would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: You talk abut picker views but you are checking the value of two labels, so you may have some issue with how you copy the data from the picker view to these labels, or perhaps with how you have linked your segues on the storyboard - the code here won't cause the problems you are describing

Comment: Thank you so much. I will check my code to see if I can resolve the issue.